# Dynamically populate masonry view on HTML web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a simple web project, and want to include a masonry view for the home page images.

I plan to host this page on Azure, using blob storage for images. My plan is to store images for the masonry view in a subDir - lets call it "masonryImages" where I can just remove/add images as I please and this will reflect on the HTML page.

What I'm looking to do is:

1. Point to the source folder of the images for the HTML page.
2. loop through this folder to a. determine how many images should be in the masonry view (expected ~50) and b. create an array of the image sources.
3. dynamically populate the HTML page with the .count and .src of these images instead of hard coding each aspect.

I have been testing with a basic masonry view:

```
 <div class="masonry">
            <div class="mItem">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300">
            </div>

            <div class="mItem">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100">
            </div>

            <div class="mItem">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/50">
            </div>

            <div class="mItem">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/600">
            </div>
 </div>
```

& for CSS

```
.masonry {
   column-count: 5;
   column-gap: 16px;
}
```

***** **MY QUESTION IS** *****

How could I dynamically create objects in a masonry view dependant on both the number of images in the source folder & also show all images by utilising their folder index.

Comment: You can't do this with client side javascript. Client side javascript will have no notion of server side directory structures for security reasons. You will need some kind of server side scripting to work with server side structures.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JonP makes entire sense when I read it that way (used to other languages over HTML/CSS). I'd prefer to avoid cloud functions to keep costs as low as possible, curious in your experience if I could load the image folder into the HTML to draw from. Lets say upon loading URL the current folder is included within that?

Comment: Nope, still need some server side scrripting to do that. HTML is purely descriptive. It can't "do" anything, that is up to the browser. You are going to need something server side to iterate that folder

Comment: Azure Files has a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api) ... unfortunately you get back XML responses rather than JSON, but it might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution, just have a hardcoded array of image URLs in Javascript, and use that to dynamically generate the page.

```js
const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min)
  max = Math.floor(max)
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
const a = [
  'https://picsum.photos/id/91/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/92/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/93/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/94/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/95/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/96/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/98/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/99/300',
  'https://picsum.photos/id/100/300',
]
const b = a.map(i => `${i}/${getRandomInt(300,400)}`)
document.querySelector('.masonry').innerHTML = b.map(s => `<img src=${s}>`).join('')
```

```css
.masonry {
  column-count: 3;
  gap: 16px;
}
.masonry img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry"></div>
```